# Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

### Today I tried to run a composer update on my laravel project and I got this error. I have no idea what caused this error.

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging::configureHandler() in /builds/anetwork/campaign-service/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/ConfigureLogging.php on line 59

Laravel version is 5.2.45 I try to get version 5.2.25 but I got same error.

Comment: composer dump-autoload

Comment: I run composer dump-autoload in post-update-cmd script before php artisan optimize run but It doesn't works.

Comment: check that timezone is set in app/config.php 'timezone' => 'UTC',  and may need to add  'log' => 'daily', to same file